# Admin role in Express API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, admin

I am creating an admin user express API, so that once the admin signup and login it can do stuff like adding category, I use mongodb, in my user model file, as I set regular user as 0 . I am testing on postman I typed my request: localhost:3000/api/category/create, then add {"name": "men", "slug":"men"}, postman just "sending request" non stop, it did not have any responses back! I mean I am confused by how to use admin role to do something like this, as I did added the adminMiddleware, can anyone help me out?

role: {
type: Number,
default: 0,
}

My middleware code:

```
    const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
    const User = require("../models/user");
    
    exports.auth = (req, res, next) => {
      try {
        const token = req.header.authorization.split("")[1];
        const isCustomAuth = token.length < 500;
    
        let decodeData;
        if (token && isCustomAuth) {
          decodeData = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
          req.UserId = decodeData?.id;
        } else {
          decodeData = jwt.decode(token);
          req.UserId = decodeData?.sub;
        }
        next();
      } catch (error) {}
    };
    
    exports.adminMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
      if (req.userId.role === 0) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "Access denied" });
      }
      next();
    };

my controller auth file:
const User = require("../models/user");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

exports.loginUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  try {
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!existingUser)
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "User does not exists." });

    const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(
      password,
      existingUser.password
    );

    if (!isPasswordCorrect)
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid credentials." });

    const token = jwt.sign(
      { email: existingUser.email, id: existingUser._id },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      { expiresIn: "3d" }
    );

    res.status(200).json({ result: existingUser, token });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

exports.signupUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { firstName, lastName, email, password, confirmPassword } = req.body;
  try {
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (existingUser)
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "User already exists." });
    if (!password == confirmPassword)
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Password don't match" });

    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

    const result = await User.create({
      email,
      password: hashedPassword,
      firstName,
      lastName,
    });

    const token = jwt.sign(
      { email: result.email, id: result._id },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      { expiresIn: "3d" }
    );

    res.status(200).json({ result, token });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

My routes:

```
router.post("/admin/login", adminMiddleware, loginUser);

//signup route
router.post("/admin/signup", adminMiddleware, signupUser);

router.post("/category/create", auth, adminMiddleware, addCategory);


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Your question lacks information. What was the request you sent, what do you mean by 'did not work'? Please provide the actual error where possible. Also it's never a good idea to swallow errors (`catch {}`).

Comment: @Einliterflasche, hi yea, I added my question, basically I am testing on postman I typed my request: localhost:3000/api/category/create, then add {"name": "men", "slug":"men"}, postman just sending request non stop, it did not have any responses back! I mean I am confused by how to use admin role to do something like this, as I did added the adminMiddleware in my code...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your function just has an error and never does anything.

My guess is that this line:

```
req.userId.role === 0
```

Throws an error, because `userId` is not an object.

If you rewrite your function like so:

```
exports.adminMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        if (req.userId.role === 0) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "Access denied" });
        }
        next();
    } catch (e) {
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "An error has occured" });
    }
};
```

You'll get a response and see the error.

---

Now once you "fix" this your middleware should work, but the purpose to a role is to do DB validation, because a malicious user can easily change the request to contain any permission. especially if it's so easy to reverse engineer as "role: 1". that's why a "login" route usually has no auth expect a rate limit. after that you're suppose to use your jwt token find the user in the DB and make sure it matches.

Comment: emmm I tried it, it gives me this error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'role')
    at exports.adminMiddleware (C:\Users\yxhou\Desktop\mern-ecommerce\ecommerce-backend\src\middleware\auth.js:35:21) ..... the thing is I used role under model that defined it like this: role: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["user", "admin"],
      default: "user",
    },
  },

Comment: as to req. UserId, i defined it right above adminMiddleware in my auth file, exports.auth = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (req.header.authorization) {
      const token = req.header.authorization.split("")[1];
      const isCustomAuth = token.length < 500;

      let decodeData;
      if (token && isCustomAuth) {
        decodeData = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        req.UserId = decodeData || {};  // here
      } else {
        decodeData = jwt.decode(token);
        req.UserId = decodeData?.sub;

Comment: Hi Tom, "that's why a "login" route usually has no auth expect a rate limit. after that you're suppose to use your jwt token find the user in the DB and make sure it matches." can you elaborate that? I have never heard rate limit etc..... so you think my auth function should be rewritten entirely? I have no idea how to do that though.....any good resources ? i am so lost so confused so frsutrated now....

Comment: In theory, when you login, the system does not knows who you are. because of that you can't really require auth on that route. your current auth function just decodes the client side JWT token, which is a good first step - but could be reverse engineered, that's why AFTER you decode it you should make sure that user actually exists in the db.

Comment: oh that make sense, so basically my auth middleware is  autenticate the user and check his token, and then authorize. then I have to add a userMiddleware (just like the adminMiddleware, despite it has some bugs in now), right? and then do I need to put the userMiddleware in my router.post("/login", loginUser)? I guess not, since userMiddleware is after what happen once the user login! btw, i am looking around online, there is passport js package, is that safe to use? and im trying to debug my req.userId.role === "admin", it does not seem work:( any help, tom?